# Stripe "webhook" error with "custom user model" (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to configure Django Stripe Subscriptions.

And now trying to setup webhook to create a new customer data by below code.

**views.py**

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from subscriptions.models import StripeCustomer  

...


# Get the user and create a new StripeCustomer
user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)

StripeCustomer.objects.create(
    user=user,
    stripeCustomerId=stripe_customer_id,
    stripeSubscriptionId=stripe_subscription_id,
)

print(user.username + ' just subscribed.')
```

I'm getting error at

**user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)**

because I'm using "custom user model". therefore I changed the above code to

**user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)**

But still, it does not work.
Is there any other way to write to get "user data"?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/app_admin/venv_ruling/ruling/subscriptions/views.py", line 124,
> in stripe_webhook
> user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

I'm following this manual to create this app
https://testdriven.io/blog/django-stripe-subscriptions/

Below is other codes.

**My models.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class StripeCustomer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripeCustomerId = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripeSubscriptionId = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CustomUser'
```

**My settings.py**

```
#used for django-allauth
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: Add your error into your post please

Comment: @Tom Hamilton Stubber I can not see any error. It just does not execute.

Comment: @Tom Hamilton Stubber I got Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app_admin/venv_ruling/ruling/subscriptions/views.py", line 124, in stripe_webhook
    user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: You have to define `objects` for your User model. Are you inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @Tom Hamilton Stubber I'm inheriting from "AbstractUser" in models.py not "AbstractBaseUser"

Comment: This error looks unrelated to the `stripe-python` client, so I will remove that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
```

And instead of using

```
user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
```

use the following:

```
User = get_user_model()
user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
```